# Django python - how do add new record every time I update the screen? instead it updates the existing record.?

Tags: python, django, django-views, model

How do add new record every time I update the screen? instead it updates the existing record.?

Here are the models.

```
class Dealer(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_name = models.CharField('Contact name', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    dealer_id = models.CharField('dealer_id', max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    dealership_name = models.CharField('Dealership name', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    dsr = models.CharField('DSR', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', blank=True, null=True)
    fax = models.CharField('Fax', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    dealer_notes = models.TextField('notes', blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField('Phone', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.CharField('Rating', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField('State', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    street = models.CharField('Street', max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField('Zip', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dealer_id


class Activity(models.Model):    
    dealer_id = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    date_created = models.DateField('date created', blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.CharField('created_by', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField('state', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    activity_notes = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.dealer_id} {self.activity_number}"
```

When it lands in dealer notes page it will get the details from the user to enter model fields and save.For each record there can be many number of activity notes. But when  I tried to add a new note it updates the existing one, i want it create a new record.

```
def create_notes(request, dealer_id):
    item, _ = Activity.objects.get_or_create(dealer_id_id=dealer_id)    
    form = ActivityForm(instance=item)   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ActivityForm(request.POST, instance=item)
       
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                
                form.save()
            except:
                pass
        else:
            return redirect('dealernotes/' + request.post.get('dealer_id_id'))
    return render(request,
                  'dealernotes.html',
                  {'form': item,},
                  )
 Can you help to create a new note every time? by activity number i should be able to update as well. 
urls:

  path('dealernotes/<str:dealer_id>?/', views.update_notes,  name='dealernotes')

How do I fix this issue?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `get_or_create` and instead just use `create`

```py
item = Activity.objects.create(dealer_id_id=dealer_id)
```

---

#### Edit 2 (scraping Edit1)

Here, Try to restructure it so that Activity is only created when you submit the form.

- **Note:** We're changing the template, don't forget about that

```py
def create_notes(request, dealer_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = ActivityForm(request.POST)
       
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
            except:
                pass
        else:
            # debugging error:
            print(form.errors.as_data())

            return redirect('dealernotes/' + request.post.get('dealer_id_id'))

    dealerObj = Dealer.objects.get(pk=dealer_id)
    form = ActivityForm(initial={'dealer_id' : dealerObj})   
    data = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'dealernotes.html', data)
```

##### Template

- We're going to replace the PK input with a dealer_id, that way the form is valid on the post

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why does it add empty rows to the table ?

Comment: I believe it's because you are creating an Activity Object for each request (GET & POST), so each time you load+submit it'll create two. I've added an edit so you're only creating the Activity on the GET, and then when you POST I'll just edit that one

Comment: I do have a Question... wouldn't it be better to **only** create an Activity Item when the form is Submitted?- That might work better as you won't have users going to the form, mashing refresh 5 times and end with 5 Blank Activity Items

Comment: I have the pk on the form. Every time when I click notes button from the page it creates a empty row in mysql db (blank columns with pk and dealer id). What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I rewrote my edit, try that. It'll only create a new row if it's got all the fields + only on a form submit. -I think the 'create new item on refresh' prob wasn't the best idea lol live and learn tho

Comment: that didn't work. it repeated the template on the webpage.

Comment: I'm an idiot. it should have used `initial` - idk wtf I was thinking, man I'm really leading you astray lol.